# Number of roots of two polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $f,g\in R[X,Y]$ and suppose that $\{ (x,y) \in R^2 : f(x,y)=g(x,y)=0\}$ is finite.
If the variable $X$ occurs only up to degree $d_1$ in both $g,f$ and $Y$ only up to degree $d_2$ is there anything that can be said about the number of common roots which is better than $(d_1+d_2)^2$?

Comment: That would depend on $f$ and $g$. And $R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an application of [Bézout's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_theorem#Rigorous_statement). If $R$ is a field, $X^{d_1}Y^{d_2}$ appears in both $g$ and $f$ and the curves $Z(g)$ and $Z(f)$ are in sufficiently general position, then you will have $\deg(f)\cdot\deg(g) = (d_1+d_2)^2$ many common roots. So, no, in general there is no better bound.

Comment: Thanx, but what happens if I know that this case does not appear.. So for example if f=X^{d_1}+Y^{d_2} + Terms of lower order and similarly g...

Comment: Dear @Tom, you still get the bound $\deg(f)\cdot\deg(g)$ which is sharp in general. In your example, you could conclude that there are at most $\max(d_1,d_2)^2$ many points in the intersection of the curves defined by $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Suppose we work over $\mathbf{C}$, then wouldn't Bernstein's theorem give me $d_1\cdot d_2$?

Comment: @Tom: I am sorry, I am unfamiliar with that theorem, or at least with the name. What does it state?

Comment: I found this yesterday: It relates the number of solutions to the mixed volume of the Newton Polytopes. In my case, the newton polytopes are simplices, conv{(d1,0),(0,d2)}... http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~myoung/bernstein